# Can I reference a sub-view from outside the view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to use a gesture recognizer in my "MyScene.m" file to move a sprite when the gesture occurs on the left half of the screen.  To do so I added a subview in the view controller with a frame matching the left side of the screen and a gesture recognizer in MyScene.  The gesture recognizer is in MyScene because it calls a method in MyScene that uses sprites from the same file.

The problem is that my new subview, "leftView", cannot be referenced from Myscene.  Is there a way to make that new subview available for use in a different implementation file?

I have included relevant code for reference below.  I'm new at this (picking it up as a hobby) and would appreciate any help you can give.  If you know of an overall better way to achieve the results I am looking for I would love to hear your advice.  Thanks!

ViewController.m:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {
      skView.showsFPS = YES;
      skView.showsNodeCount = YES;


      // Create and configure the scene.
      SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
      scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
      //skView.scene.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, skView.scene.physicsWorld.gravity.dy*-1);
      // Present the scene.
      [skView presentScene:scene];

        UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        [leftView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [leftView setAlpha:0.2];
        [self.view addSubview:leftView];
    }
}
```

MyScene.m:

```
@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) 
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(self) action:@selector(screenSwipedRight)];
    swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeRight)];
    }


-(void)screenSwipedRight
{
    NSLog(@"Screen was swiped to the right");
    CGFloat percentToRight = 1-(self.playerOne.position.x / self.view.bounds.size.width);
    NSTimeInterval timeToRight = self.horizontalRunSpeed * percentToRight;
    NSLog(@"Percent to right = %f",percentToRight);
    NSLog(@"Time to right = %f",timeToRight);
    SKAction *moveNodeRight = [SKAction moveToX:self.view.bounds.size.width-self.playerOne.size.width duration:timeToRight];
    [self.playerOne runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[moveNodeRight]]];
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I posted an answer then deleted it.  I'm actually a little confused on what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: To summarize, I want to trigger a gesture recognizer when the user swipes the left, and only left, side of the screen.  If they swipe on the right I do not want the gesture to be recognized.  To do that I added a subview to the left side of the screen.  Objective-C allows you to set gesture recognizers to only react in certain views/subviews.  The problem is that the leftView isn't coming up as an option in MyScene.m.

Comment: And it's going to effect a view that's on the screen at the same time?

Comment: No it will be moving a sprite.  I edited my previous comment to add some more detail.

Comment: Hmm, you're view heirarchy is just mind-bogglingly confusing to me.  I have no idea what is going on at all here.  The swipe on the left side of the screen, I get that it's effecting a sprite.  Is it effecting a sprite in a different view?  Or is the sprite on the screen (visible) at the same time as this left view with the swipe gesture recognizer?  Could you perhaps try getting this to work with a far more simple example (just reaching into one view from another, etc)

Comment: The sprite is in MyScene.m.  I apologize if the view hierarchy is confusing.  As I said, I'm a hobbyist trying to teach myself.  Also, if there is an easier way to do this I am all ears.  I am here entirely to learn.

Comment: Instead of adding this leftView, why not just use the gesture recognizer's locationInView: property to determine where the initial touch is on the screen, and do nothing if it's not on the left side?

Comment: I did not know that was an option!  I'll research locationInView.  Thanks a ton!  This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments by rdelmar.  Quote below:

"Instead of adding this leftView, why not just use the gesture recognizer's locationInView: property to determine where the initial touch is on the screen, and do nothing if it's not on the left side?" - rdelmar

This solution will work perfectly.  Using the locationInView property will allow the gesture to be recognized only on one side of the screen.  Thanks to rdelmar and nhgrif for taking the time to help.